# Check if @XmlElement have name attribute

Tags: java, reflection, jaxb

I'm using reflection to fill jaxb-object with data from hashMap.
If @XmlElement have name attribute, I should use it, if not, I should use field name.

```
XmlElement anno = field.getAnnotation(XmlElement.class);
String name = anno.name();
```

I found, if name attribute does not set manually(e.g. used simple @XmlElement annotation), name field value is "##default". To check if attribute set, I use this code:

```
if(!"##default".equals(name)){
```

But I don't think it is acceptable. How can I do it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A value of `"##default"` (the default) on the name property of the `@XmlElement` annotation indicates that the XML element name should be derived from the field.  Therefore the code you have is perfectly valid:

```
if(!"##default".equals(name)){
```

A user could not specify

```
@XmlElement(name="##default")
```

To get the following XML:

```xml
<root>
    <##default>Hello World</##default>
</root>
```

**Javadoc Reference**

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html#name%28%29

Comment: Do you mean there is no better way?

Comment: @rdo - Essentially.  If you are looking at the `@XmlElement` annotation then comparing the `name` property to the value `##default` would be the best thing to do.